# Apache "Alias" excluding some domains

Tags: apache, alias, subdomain

I have wampp server installed on windows. On this server i have multiple subdomains running alongwith some primary domains using virtual hosts. A requirement was to implement robots.txt for all subdomains automatically. For example:

```
site1.example.com

site2.example.com

site3.example.com

site1.example.net

site2.example.net
```

So for this in http.conf i have written:

```
Alias /robots.txt D:/wampp/static-files/override-robots.txt
```

The above fullfills the requirement for all subdomains on example.com & example.net and every new subdomain created will have this robots.txt by default and one don't have to put separate robots.txt for each, but the problem is that some primary domains are also on this server and there robots.txt also get run from the above. For example:

```
www.primarydomain1.com

www.primardomain2.com
```

Now, what i want is that all subdomains of example.com & example.net will have robots.txt automatically run from above excluding all primary domains. May be Apache Alias is not the best way of doing this, so any help or hint regarding it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and run i found a solution for this and i think it may help someone if i share here:

Basically, in httpd.conf file i have written:

```
Alias /robots.txt D:/wampp/static-files/override-robots.txt
```

so this will run for each and every domain and subdomain but it can be overriden for a specific domain/subdomain which are defined in vhosts file i.e. httpd-vhosts.conf, inside the vhosts container of each domain/subdomain. So for example if i need to serve different robots.txt for www.primarydomain1.com :

```
<VirtualHost 212.212.212.212>
  DocumentRoot "D:/WebSites-Data/primarydomain1.com"
  ServerName primarydomain1.com
  ServerAlias www.primarydomain1.com
  ErrorLog "logs/primarydomain1.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/primarydomain1.com-access.log" combined
  Alias /robots.txt D:/WebSites-Data/primarydomain1.com/this-robots.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

So in this way if somebody hits www.primarydomain1.com/robots.txt apache will serve robots.txt from

```
D:/WebSites-Data/primarydomain1.com/this-robots.txt
```

and for other domains/subdomains it keeps serving from:

```
Alias /robots.txt D:/wampp/static-files/override-robots.txt
```

This also leads to the fact that we can override httpd.conf some settings for a specific domain, if we define it in a vhosts container.

The above solution is working fine for me. If there are any cons of this solution, please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: Works for me after 3 years. Thanks!